Why is plink access granted but nothing occurs even with right credentials?
plink.exe -ssh -l LOGIN -pw PASSWORD -N -R <remoteip>:47108:127.0.0.1:10808 -R <remoteip>:11597:127.0.0.1:14434 <remoteip>

Using username "login". Access granted.
Press Return to begin session.

But when I press return nothing occurs and I try to connect but is not working.
This same command worked well a few days ago, but I don't know why now it is not working.
GatewayPorts is enabled with clientspecified in ssh server config but I don't know why is not connecting. Is there a way to debug or check why is not connecting??

